# Fix double call and get before value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am learning JQuery by example. Please check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4tjof34d/2/

I have two problems:
1 : `showText()` gets called twice when a person hits enter and thus `console.log(this.id+ " " +this.value);` gets called twice, What do I add so that it only gets called once?

2: I get the id and value of the textbox, but I also want to know what was the old id and value so that I can do a comparison test. How do I do that?

eg:

```
var oldValue = ? // How do I do this?
var newValue =  this.value;
```

Then I can do something like:

```
if(newValue != oldValue)
{
 // Do .ajax() - update DB
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your first issue showText is called twice ie,on blur and on enter  

change your blur function as follows

`$('.input').blur(showText).keyup(function (e) {
    if(e.which === 13) { 
      this.blur();
    }
});`
for second issue i will go with a global variable as flag
http://jsfiddle.net/x1ez7Lek/6/

Comment: I just tested the code and it seems to work, but how did you do it without using stopPropagation? Also, I think there is a problem with "prev" because when I comment out the `if(this.id!=prev)` and I do `console.log(this.id+ " " +this.value+ " " +prev);` I get `prev` always as null

Comment: stopPropagation was something that came to mind at first, the i saw much easier way to solve you problem. You are already calling the function on blur then why not just trigger it on keyup

Comment: I added to my previous comment, refresh the page please

Comment: id in prev is updated in `if()`, you cannot remove that

Comment: Aha, now I think I get it (?), correct me if I am wrong, but the first time prev is null, then it gets the previous value and keeps updating the previous value? yes?

Comment: Ok, got the logic, and moved up the console.log() statement and it all works, voted and selected your answer, thanks!

Comment: Hey again, I am having a problem, if the person clicks the first three dots (A) and enters stuff it works, but if you go to the second three dots (B) and click, then it holds the value of A instead :(

For example: click the first three dots and enter the value 111, then click the 2nd three dots and enter the value of 222 and see the console output...

Comment: i dont see any problem, corresponding values of the input fields are logged to the console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65091/discussion-between-ryan-and-shan).